# pandas duplicated records find same and different columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a record like

```
raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
        'name': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'age_group' : [1, 2, 2, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'name','age_group'])
```

which contains a (duplicated) ID and some additional columns. Below

```
ids = df.subject_id
df[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])]
```

will return already only the duplicated records. Now I would want to better understand the columns which are

- the same
- different

for each duplicated record, i.e. in this case here I would want to receive  the offending duplicate IDs and the respective columns where the rows are different.

```
  subject_id name
1          2    B
2          2    B
3          3    C
4          3    D
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're looking for?

Comment: Isn't that already included? I am looking for the duplicated rows by Id and would only like to see the columns where the values differ

Comment: I think my confusion comes from looking at `subject_id == 2`, where `age_group` differs but is not included, while you do have `name`, which doesn't differ for those rows.

Comment: I see -updated the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
>>>duplicated_ids
  subject_id name  age_group
1          2    B          2
2          2    B          2
3          3    C          1
4          3    D          1
```

Then

```
>>>othercols = duplicated_ids.columns[1:]
>>>outcols = ['subject_id']
>>>for col in othercols:
       if not duplicated_ids.drop_duplicates(['subject_id', col], keep=False).empty:
           outcols.append(col)

>>>duplicated_ids.loc[:, outcols]
  subject_id name
1          2    B
2          2    B
3          3    C
4          3    D
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, which allows for exploring and better understanding where differences occur.

We will set up a column that indicates we have found a row where a given `subject_id` does not match what we have previously recorded for their `name` or their `age_group`, i.e. we've found a difference. This column will be called `diff_indicator` and is binary `0` if not different from previously recorded values, and `1` if it is different.

```
storage_dict = {}


for i in range(len(df)):
    if not df.loc[i, 'subject_id'] in storage_dict:
        storage_dict[df.loc[i, 'subject_id']] = (df.loc[i, 'name'], df.loc[i, 'age_group'])
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i, 'name'] != storage_dict[df.loc[i, 'subject_id']][0]) | \
    (df.loc[i, 'age_group'] != storage_dict[df.loc[i, 'subject_id']][1]):
        df.loc[i, 'diff_indicator'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'diff_indicator'] = 0
```

From here we can explore where there exists a difference.

```
>>> df.loc[df['diff_indicator'] == 1]['subject_id'].unique()
array(['2', '3'], dtype=object)

>>> df.loc[df['diff_indicator'] == 1]
  subject_id name  age_group  diff_indicator
2          2    B          1             1.0
4          3    D          1             1.0
```

There are many ways to query this depending on your interest. We can return the desired output like this...

```
>>> df.loc[df['subject_id'].isin(df.loc[df['diff_indicator'] == 1]['subject_id'].unique())]
  subject_id name  age_group  diff_indicator
1          2    B          2             0.0
2          2    B          1             1.0
3          3    C          3             0.0
4          3    D          1             1.0
```

We can see the first two columns of this data frame are the desired output.